# media print css on specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing

I use @media print for print html page.

`@media` print work fine in simple html page.

But when I call javascript the `@media` css not work on document.

My javascript code is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'mydiv', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }

</script>
```

How can write media print css for work on specific div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to write the CSS into that new window.  The new window is a completely separate environment from the window that opens it, and the CSS in the original window will have absolutely no effect on the popup.